# What's the purpose of fseek(..) function?

Tags: file, io, operating-system

Why are we being forced to use fseek function for positioning file handle instead of calling file read function with an extra parameter like "filePos" ?

Comment: If you can provide an example, for others to understand your question better, you might get a better answer.

Comment: Something like [`pread()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/read.html), perhaps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a question of design. If you had a file read function with a position parameter, then you'd need to set that parameter every time you did a file read.

Part of the problem is the eunuch's library and file system was poorly designed and we live with mistakes made in the 1960's and 1970's.

Most contemporary systems read files in logical blocks. They had system services for specifying the logical block number to read.